# Python pack IP string to bytes

Tags: python, ip-address, pack, unpack, inet-aton

I want to kind of implement my own `struct.pack` specific function to pack an IP string (i.e. "192.168.0.1") to a 32-bit packed value, without using the `socket.inet_aton` built in method.

I got so far:

```
ip = "192.168.0.1"
hex_list = map(hex, map(int, ip.split('.')))
# hex list now is : ['0xc0', '0xa8', '0x0', '0x01']
```

**My question is:**
How do I get from that `['0xc0', '0xa8', '0x0', '0x01']` to `'\xc0\xa8\x00\x01'`, (this is what I'm getting from `socket.inet_aton(ip)`?

(**And also** - How is it possible that there is a NUL (`\x00`) in the middle of that string? I think I lack some understanding of the `\x` format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string comprehension to format as you like:

```
ip = "192.168.0.1"
hex_list = map(int, ip.split('.'))
hex_string = ''.join(['\\x%02x' % x for x in hex_list])
```

or as a one liner:

```
hex_string = ''.join(['\\x%02x' % int(x) for x in ip.split('.')])
```

Comment: I tried that, but I get '\\xc0\\xa8\\x00\\x01' which is not equal to  '\xc0\xa8\x00\x01' . Is it the same?

Comment: the `\\ ` is just Python's way of showing you a single `\ `. change the `'\\x%02x'` to `r'\x%02x'` and note that you get the same result.

Comment: I know that, but will it be the same when I send this address over? Will it be the same as the value recieved by `socket.inet_aton`?

Comment: escaping strings is somewhat of a black art.  the answer is: it depends.  Every step along the way you have the potential for someone to interpret the string and thus need some sort of escaping.  I was simply answering your question of how to get the indicated string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative:

Can you use [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) and [`to_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) <sub>(python 3.2)</sub>?

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> address = ipaddress.IPv4Address('192.168.0.1')
>>> address_as_int = int(address)
>>> address_as_int.to_bytes(4, byteorder='big')
b'\xc0\xa8\x00\x01'
```

Note that you may actually only need the integer.

Can be shorter obviously, but wanted to show all steps clearly :)

Answer (score 1):

Based loosely off @Stephen's answer but returns a string with the actual bytes rather than a string with literal slashes:

```
def pack_ip(ip):
    num_list = map(int, ip.split('.'))
    return bytearray(num_list)

src_ip = pack_ip('127.0.0.255')
print(repr(src_ip))
```

Works in Python 2 and 3. Returns a `b''` rather than a string, matching best practice for Python3.